# Return failing in a windows executable

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

[image]I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to create a utility for firmware upgrade.
I am facing a very perplexing problem here.

```
printf("Before \n");
if(any_device_active()) 
stat=switchover(ni_handle,&SWover);
else return; <<<<--------Second ONE
printf("switch over stat =%d\n",stat);
Sleep(1000);
return; <<<<<---------Third ONE
```

As observed the first return is successful.
All the returns after that fail.
I don't seem to get the problem.
I don't even know what to look for.
Also by the way the `switchover` function is empty and just returns a 0.
`any_device_active` just returns 0 and prints a list , no problem there.
This is the error code the visual debugger throws 0xc0000409.

Comment: Can you show us the code before first return? Isn't it a part of a `if`? Otherwise the code after the first return makes no sense.

Comment: The first return i have removed as it was causing confusions.But the main problem there was that a return there used to work normally while the second and the third are failing.

Comment: When `any_device_active()` returns `0` the `else` part of the `if` will get executed, so the function returns without calling `switchover()` or printing `"switch over stat ="`

Comment: The problem does not lie in the logic , It lies in how return is placed.If i place return before the if statement the program exits successfully and when it comes in else part it terminates abruptly.There is absolutely no problem in logic.The question can be reiterated as return succeeds prior to a statement but fails afterwards.Namely after switchover.(Even if not in else)

Comment: Try posting the whole function. Perhaps it's meant to return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0xC0000409 is STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN: It means some write to a pointer overwrote something it shouldn't have on the stack, and the C Run-Time Library's security code in your function's epilog detected it.

You have some kind of buffer overflow bug or improper pointer use in your switchover() function.

Comment: Thanks i am investigating in the same direction.Will update accordingly.